# Google VR View HLS - Streaming on iOS

Tags: ios, html, http-live-streaming, google-vr

So I'm currently trying to build the default current version of Google VR View, and run the example video, but with a HLS stream instead of an .mp4.

The HLS stream works in other players but I'm only getting audio come through on the iOS device. The iOS version is 10 and is running the html5 player in safari.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and have a potential solution?

Comment: Could you please give more information? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I'm basically asking if anyone knows how to get HLS streaming working on iOS using Google VR? I can currently get audio through but not see the video.

Comment: @reeceFPVR, having the exact same issues. Started with HLS.js, but that does not work on iOS. Then I used native HTML5 video element with an HLS stream in it, which actually works. Then I added A-Frame and tried to project the video onto a sphere, and got audio + black screen. Then tried Google VRView, and also got audio + black screen. [Here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3151) they say it is a shader issue. Hope someone solves this soon.